# TinyMCE: Why font size, family, color are not working?

Tags: tinymce, font-size

I just started working with TinyMCE and everything seems ok so far, except one thing. When I wanna try to change the style (like color, font family, font size, so on) in the TinyMCE, but it only print the tags, like this (without "style= font-size:)

```
<p><span  16px;">test</span></p>
```

but of course it will not actually be able to change the style this way, because as I know it should be like :

```
<p><span style='font-size: 16px;">test</span></p>
```

shouldn't it be like this? Why is that? How I will be able to change the style in TinyMCE?  What I'm missing..?

Thanks

Comment: did you solve this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using php framework, there is a chance that the input is escaped for XSS filtering. 
Try disable the XSS filtering.

I myself encountered same problem using CodeIgniter php.

XSS enabled :

```
$this->input->post('content', true);
```

XSS disabled :

```
$this->input->post('content');
```

Be sure to know what is XSS attack before disabling it. I disabled it as temporary solution for me. 
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to configure tinymce the way i accepts your desired atributes. You will need to change the [valid_elements](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3avalid_elements) setting.